# Pre-populate initiation form values with InfoPath

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath, sharepoint-designer

I'm currently exploring some new features in SP2010, Designer and InfoPath regarding Workflows and Initiation Forms. What I want is to manual start a workflow on a existing list item, give the workflow some input values with the initiation form and then process the workflow in its whole.

The workflow is a sequential set of operations updating the current list item. No waits or other input is required. Once started it should complete immediately after the set-operations.

The problem is, I would like to pre-populate some of the initiation form parameters with values from the list item itself. The user then has the choice to change this, or leave it be.

I tried a couple of things, like trying to get a secondary data connection up and running using the query string parameter in the URL (id={id}). It looks like InfoPath and SharePoint automatically set some configuration settings, and that InfoPath is running in a cut-down version; less stuff to configure, no code behind.

Any tips, advice, solutions to my problem :-)?

Thanks in advance,

Patrick

Answer (score 1):

The workflow process does not enter the init activity's codebehind until **after** the workflow's InfoPath Initiation Form has been submitted.  There must be a way to sync the data fields of this form with those of the Association Form, based on the namespaces of the two forms, but I have not yet found exactly how to do that.

Comment: Follow on: It is possible to have data transfer from the Association Form to the Initiation Form, provided you use the **same** form with the same URN. What I have yet to learn is now is how to extend the Initiation form to have additional, "non-core" fields that are custom to an individual workflow experience.